# Android notification : bug when using multiple setOnClickPendingIntent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I have got a strange bug.

I have got a notification with 3 buttons (back, next, play/pause). I want to set a different pendingIntent on each of these three buttons which launch a service. Here is my code:

```
    Intent playPauseIntent = new Intent(MyApp.mainActivity, NotificationService.class);
    playPauseIntent.putExtra("do_action", "play");
    contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notifPlayPauseImageView, PendingIntent.getService(MyApp.mainActivity, 0, playPauseIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));            

    Intent nextRadioIntent = new Intent(MyApp.mainActivity, NotificationService.class);
    nextRadioIntent.putExtra("do_action", "next");
    contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notifNextImageView, PendingIntent.getService(MyApp.mainActivity, 0, nextRadioIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

    Intent previousRadioIntent = new Intent(MyApp.mainActivity, NotificationService.class);
    previousRadioIntent.putExtra("do_action", "previous");
    contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notifPreviousImageView, PendingIntent.getService(MyApp.mainActivity, 0, previousRadioIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

    notification.contentView = contentView;
    mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

Then, in my service, I get the intent and the value of "do_action" defined as an extra:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,  int flags, int startId) { 

   if(intent != null && intent.getExtras() != null)
   {
      String action = (String) intent.getExtras().get("do_action"); // BUG HERE ! I always get "previous" !!!
   }       
}
```

The bug is here... I always get "previous" when I get the "do_action" value (not only when I click on the previous button, also when I click on the play or next buttons).

Anybody can help me to solve this problem ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have used same request code `0` for all of your `Pendingintent`. You should use different `REQUEST_CODE` for different `PendingIntent`:

```
PendingIntent.getService(MyApp.mainActivity, REQUEST_CODE, Intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
```

**Try this:**

```
Intent playPauseIntent = new Intent(MyApp.mainActivity, NotificationService.class);
playPauseIntent.putExtra("do_action", "play");
contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notifPlayPauseImageView, PendingIntent.getService(MyApp.mainActivity, 0, playPauseIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));            

Intent nextRadioIntent = new Intent(MyApp.mainActivity, NotificationService.class);
nextRadioIntent.putExtra("do_action", "next");
contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notifNextImageView, PendingIntent.getService(MyApp.mainActivity, 1, nextRadioIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

Intent previousRadioIntent = new Intent(MyApp.mainActivity, NotificationService.class);
previousRadioIntent.putExtra("do_action", "previous");
contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notifPreviousImageView, PendingIntent.getService(MyApp.mainActivity, 2, previousRadioIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

notification.contentView = contentView;
mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: Happy to help you :)